Help with finding error in my proof for a problem about the probability of $\epsilon$-regularity in a random graph
Problem (Alon and Spencer 17.6.1):


Show that for every fixed $\varepsilon > 0$ and $0 < p < 1$ there is an $m_0 = m_0(\varepsilon, p)$ so that for every $n > 2m > m_0$, the probability that two fixed disjoint sets $A$ and $B$, each of size $m$, of the random graph $G(n, p)$ do not form an $\varepsilon$-regular pair is smaller than $\varepsilon$.


My question is very basic, even though it may seem lengthy – please help. FYI, the problem statement is in the link above.
I had this solution (after a hint from Bob Krueger in this post).
$$P(A \text{ and }B \text{ don't form an } \epsilon \text{ regular pair}) = P(\text{at least one pair } X \subseteq A, Y \subseteq B \text{ exists such that } |d(A, B) - d(X, Y)| > \epsilon)$$
$$\le \sum_{\text{all pairs (X $\in$ A, Y $\in$ B) with $X \geq \epsilon|A| \text{ and } Y \geq \epsilon |B|$}} \left(\text{Pr}(|d(A, B) - d(X, Y)| > \epsilon \right)$$
$$\le \sum_{\text{ all pairs (X $\subseteq$ A, Y \subseteq B)}} \left(\text{Pr}(|d(A, B) - d(X, Y)| > \epsilon \right)$$
$$\le 4^m \cdot \text{max}_{X \subseteq A, Y \subseteq B}\left(\text{Pr}(|d(A, B) - d(X, Y)| > \epsilon \right)) \qquad (\star)$$
I'm not even going to go forward with the Chernoff bounding here. Obviously, $\text{max}_{X \subseteq A, Y \subseteq B}\left(\text{Pr}(|d(A, B) - d(X, Y)| > \epsilon \right))$ will be some real number between $0$ and $1$, for the sake of brevity let it be $a$. Now, note that the upper bound on the probability in $(\star)$ should be less than $\epsilon$, as dictated by the problem statement. That is, $$4^m \cdot a < \epsilon$$
$$\implies m < \log_4{\frac{\epsilon}{a}}.$$
Now here's where the contradiction is happening. As the problem statement indicates, we should be able to pick $m$ as large as $\frac{n}{2}$, where $n$ is the number of vertices in the graph and that has no upper bound. On the other hand, our proof above indicates that there is an upper limit to $m$.
Either I am misunderstanding the problem or there is something stupidly wrong with my solution which I am not able to figure out at all.

$a$ is a function of $n$.

@JamieRadcliffe How? Given the two sunsets $A, B$, it is irrelevant how big of a graph these two subsets are in. The $\epsilon$-regularity of these two sets is independent of $n$ and only dependent on the edges between these sets themselves. Where am I wrong?

Rather, $a$ is a function of $m$, because $|A|=|B|=m$ and $|X|, |Y| \ge \epsilon m$ - it's important not to forget the lower bound on $|X|$ and $|Y|$ until after you take that maximum. You'll get $a = e^{-\Omega(m^2)}$, and so $4^m \cdot \alpha > \epsilon$ will hold for all large enough $m$.
